AIOGRAM 3.7.0: обращение к функции при каждом срабатывании роутера
Всем привет! Мне нужно, чтобы при каждом срабатывании роутера было обращение к функции. В моём случае - при поступлении сообщения шла сверка данных пользователя с базой
# Вот как это работает сейчас:
@router.message(Command('start'))
async def start(message: Message):
    await data.check_user(message.from_user)
    await message.answer(load_json("starting", message.from_user.language_code))


@router.message(Command('credits'))
async def show_credits(message: Message):
    await data.check_user(message.from_user)
    await message.answer(load_json("credits", message.from_user.language_code))


@router.message(Command('connect'))
async def show_connect_instructions(message: Message):
    await data.check_user(message.from_user)
    await message.answer(load_json("connect", message.from_user.language_code))


@router.message(Command('privacy'))
async def show_privacy(message: Message):
    await data.check_user(message.from_user)
    await message.answer(load_json("privacy", message.from_user.language_code))

load_json() - подгрузка текста сообщения из JSON-файла в соответствии с языком пользователя
Как сделать так, чтобы каждый раз не прописывать функцию check_user(), а она сама вызывалась при срабатывании роутера? Можно ли это прописать при объявлении роутера? Спасибо <3

Ну так повесь фильтр на роутер и все

А не, фильтр в данном случае не то будет. Миддлварь лучше использовать наверное. Вообще, не очень понятно, что нужно-то? Скорректируй вопрос и опиши задачу более подробно

@CausonQ я имел в виду, чтобы в сам роутер было заложено data.check_user()

Ну в роутер можно фильтр прописать. И тогда, если фильтр пройдет, хендлеры, которые в этом роутере сработают

Что делает функция check_user()?

@BenPuls Она синхронизирует пользователя с БД

Да, тогда мидлвари будут самым оптимальным решением.
